# Can (former?) Singapore PR retire abroad and still receive CPF Life payouts?

Tags: singapore, cpf, pr

I've been a Singapore PR for quite some time now, and I do plan to stay for as long as I can still find employment. However, I don't think I would ever be able to get a property of my own here, and without it spending retirement in Singapore doesn't look realistic.

I've tried to research this online, but every single piece of information I could find deals with how to *withdraw* your CPF savings when or if you leave SG.

Does anyone know if it's possible to retire to other country (not Malaysia) but *keep* your money in CPF and still receive your CPF Life payouts for the rest of your life?

Or, more general question, do you *have* to withdraw your savings from CPF if you no longer reside in Singapore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, you can keep your savings in CPF essentially forever even if you leave Singapore.  (Or that's the rule at the moment, anyway; you have no control over CPF investments and are subject to the whims of the Singapore government here.)  In fact, the process of getting your CPF money out is [rather bureaucratic](https://www.cpf.gov.sg/Members/Schemes/schemes/other-matters/cpf-withdrawals-on-other-grounds#Item1699) and will definitely not "just happen" on its own.

That said, there are several notable complications:

- Maintaining PR outside Singapore requires a valid Re-Entry Permit (REP).   REPs have to be renewed every 5 years, and essentially require that you're living in Singapore.
- CPF LIFE payouts can only be made into Singaporean bank accounts.  These are very difficult to open if you're not a Singaporean resident -- although once opened, nobody will check to see if you're still one.

Comment: Thanks! Was hoping that someone from singaporeexpats might stop by to answer :)

Comment: @jpatokal, What do you mean by "rather bureaucratic"? I was under the impression that you can withdraw all your CPF money once you stop being a citizen and break all ties with Singapore, and [such application](https://www.cpf.gov.sg/Members/Schemes/schemes/other-matters/cpf-withdrawals-on-other-grounds#Item1709) typically has a 100% success rate. Is that right?

Comment: @Pacerier You need to provide a lot of supporting documentation, some of it notarized.

Answer (score 9):

Will post an answer of my own as well for completeness sake. I sent the same question to CPF directly, here's what they said:

> Yes, you are right in saying that your Singapore Permanent Resident
>   (SPR) status will be revoked when you are no longer residing in
>   Singapore for a substantial amount of time.
>
> We would like to clarify that you can withdraw your CPF savings at any
>   time when you choose to reside in other countries besides Singapore
>   and Malaysia once your SPR status have been revoked. Hence, you will
>   be able to keep your monies in your CPF account to earn the high
>   interest respectively, which will also help to build your retirement
>   savings. You can click on this link for more information on the
>   withdrawal:
>   https://www.cpf.gov.sg/members/schemes/schemes/other-matters/cpf-withdrawals-on-other-grounds#Item1699.
>
> If you are no longer an SPR and have already joined CPF LIFE, you will
>   still be able to receive these payouts for as long as you live.
>
> As CPF LIFE is for Singaporeans and SPR, if you are not a SPR when you
>   are 55 years old, you would not be joining CPF LIFE.